# C# or C++ sandboxed assembly

Tags: c#, c++, assembly, sandbox

I'm thinking of writing a program that involves including super fast Assembly or as it dosn't have to be human readable it could be Machine Code in C++ or C#. However I also have other possibly more troublesome requirements.

I would need to be able to:

- Store machine code programs in normal variables / object instances, for example strings "40 9B 7F 5F ..." to edit and run them.
- Have the programs able to output data. I saw an example where one had a pointer to an int that it could use.
- Have the programs not able to output data anywhere else. For example to not be able to perform such actions as to delete files, view the system spec or change the state of the memory of the C++ or C# program they are contained within.

For example, it could be something like this:

```
machine n;
n = "40 9B 7F";
n[1] = "5F";
// 'n' is now "40 5F 7F"
unsigned short s = 2;
n.run(&s);
// while 'n' was running it may have changed 's' but would not have been able to
// change anything else anywhere on the system including in this C++ / C# program
```

According to the wiki link Michael Dorgan posted "asm(std::string);" runs the String as assembler and it's also easy to referance variables from the C++ part of the program. Editing a std::String is easy and Alex has noted that I can ensure that the code is safe by not allowing unsafe commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you restrict the subset of supported instructions, you can do what you want more or less easily.

First, you have to parse and decode an input instruction to see if it's in the supported subset (most of parsing/decoding can be done just once). Then you need to execute it.

But before executing, there's one important thing to take care of. Based on the decoded details of the instruction and the CPU registers state, you have to calculate the memory addresses that the instruction is going to access as data (including on-stack locations) or transfer control to. If any of those are outside of the established limits, fire alarm. Otherwise, if it's a control transferring instruction (e.g. jmp, jz), you must additionally ensure that the address it passes control to is not only within the memory, where all these instructions lie, but also is the address of one of those instructions and not an address inside of any of them (e.g. 1 or 2 bytes from the beginning of a 3+ bytes long instruction). Passing control anywhere else is a no-no. You do not want these instructions to pass control to any standard library functions either because you won't be able to control execution there and they're not always safe when supplied with bogus/malicious inputs. Also, these instructions must not be able to modify themselves.

If all is clear, you can either emulate the instruction or more or less directly execute it (control passing instructions will likely have to be always emulated because you want to stop execution after every instruction). For the latter you can create a modifiable function containing these things:

1. Code to save CPU registers of the caller and load them with the state for the instruction being executed.
2. The instruction.
3. The reverse of step 1: code to save post-execution register state and restore the caller's register state.

You can try this approach.

Comment: May I check I understand this so far. I think this is correct answer. int asm_var, other_var; String s = "movl %ecx, %eax fxam jp SC17"; asm(s); There's 3 instructions in 's'. If for example 'movl' allowed for dangerous operations I could ensure that 's' contained no 'movl' commands when I ran it with 'asm'. However as I want 's' to have some internal state and output then I need to allow some writing to variables, so for example only 'write_to state_var' but not 'write_to private_var'. Is there a list of the asm commands reguarding whats for computation and whats for writing to disk etc... ?

Comment: You need to have separate memory for the encoded instructions themselves and for their state. The latter includes the state of the CPU registers (some data structure must hold those) and any additional scratchpad-like memory for those instructions to work with. For example, if the instructions "want" to calculate CRC32 using a table look-up method, they can calculate that table and store it there.

Comment: I only need to pass controll back to the calling function which presumably occurs by default when and if the asm ends. From other code I've seen it looks like you can use varible names in you'r program and don't need to work out memory addresses of things.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking w.r.t. editing and goto. The assembler will have to assemble/encode all instructions, note their addresses and if anyone of them needs to jump to another, the assembler will take the difference between the addresses of the two instructions and put it inside of the jumping instruction. There're a number of different x86 jump instructions. Some just jump, others jump only if a certain condition is met (e.g. a specific flag is set to 0 or 1 in the EFLGAGS register).

Comment: So if I allow those I have to make sure the jump is to locations inside the asm itself, presumably it starts and 0 and is as long as it has instructions.

Comment: Functions are typically invoked with the CALL instruction. They return to the caller by means of the RET instruction. You can use RET as well. Just stop execution if you encounter RET as the next instruction and have RET in your assembly code where you want it stop. Or it can be UD2 instead of RET, whatever you like can be the termination marker as long as it doesn't fall into the subset of instructions you emulate/execute.

Comment: As I said earlier, the range check isn't sufficient. Jumps must jump at the beginnings of the instructions. If they jump in the middle, it's a totally different instruction for the CPU. And if you allow that, either the code escapes from your sandbox or you have to reparse/decode the instruction again.

Comment: So encountering the end of the String or an unknown command including RET ends the asm program and returns to the caller.

Comment: A Jump instruction must be the first instruction? Thats going to be a bit problematic. I'd need several asm("..."); and to jump between them then if I wanted any sort of flow controll.

Comment: No. Perhaps, I misspoke. Suppose in your code you have 2 instructions, `and ax,3` and `xor eax,4`, going one after the other and encoded as `66,25,03,00` and `83,F0,04` respectively. A jump instruction jumping to these instructions is only allowed to jump to the address containing `66`, where the first instruction begins, or to the address containing `83`, where the second instruction begins. If you allow a jump to the address containing `25`, the sequence of bytes `25,03,00,83,F0` representing the `and eax,F0830003` instruction, is unexpected. You don't want surprises like this.

Comment: Jumping to the `00` byte will jump to the `add [ebx+XXXX04F0],al` instruction encoded by `00,83,F0,04` and the next two bytes from memory. This instruction can easily crash or corrupt your app. This is an escape from the sandbox.

Comment: jmp doesn't have to be the first instruction at all. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks :¬) cleared lots of stuff. The app for this is genetic programming where a program is evolved to be the simplest program that outputs a given series of numbers, rest of series beyond the end of what was typed then infered, for example 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 -> 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 etc... uses program objects thats contents include a list of numbers that can "run" and functions somewhat like assembler code, but much slower because it's not. Am going to speed this program up. Also inspired by the 32 byte programs at http://www.pouet.net/prodlist.php?platform[]=MS-Dos&type[]=32b&order=views

Comment: Sorry about trying to squeese all that into the charecter limit :¬P To re-itterate I've already writtain this program in C++ and I'm going to use this assembler stuff to make it run faster.

Comment: If you care about speed more than about instructions being valid x86 instructions, invent your own, simpler instructions and emulate them. That'll be much simpler and work much faster than complex x86 decoding, checks and execution with register content swaps.

Answer (score 3):

Sandboxing native machine code is non-trivial. If you really want that take a look at [NACL](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/) from google which implements a machine code sandbox for browsers.

What is more practical is to use .NET IL instead of machine code and use a sandboxed (or hosted) AppDomain. This comes much closer and still is fast due to the dynamically jit-compilation to machine code.

An alternative you have is to use Windows builtin rights management and spawn a new process with restricted rights. Never done that so I don't know if you can reduce the target processes rights as much as you want. Anyways that would be a pure win32 process just running machine code, so you lose any ability of using .NET in the sandboxed process.

Comment: What happens if the IL code in an AppDomain instance wants to for example open a file for writing?

Comment: The .NET framework will check the security settings of the AppDomain and throw a security execption if it isn't allowed to do it. For what you want to do you should pretty much disable everything and provide your own API to the outside world.

Comment: Cool, ty. I'm going for Alex aproach at the moment but it's cirtainly something I'll keep in mind. I don't know for sure his aproach is going to work yet but it looks more what I was thinking even if I have to do more legwork myself to get the sandboxing working. If I could set multiple answers as correct then this would be correct as well.

Answer (score 2):

*Update based on comments:*

This is far from a trivial task.  You have to implement a linker, assembler (to scan and sandbox) and loader.

I wonder what the use case is -- for my example I'll assume you want to to have an assembly contest where people submit solutions to problems and you "test" them.

This is the best solution I can think of:

- Have a hosting program that takes as input assembly language.
- Invoke the assembler to compile and link the assembly program.
- Create a protected virtual environment for the program to run in (how you do this depends on the platform) which runs as a user that has *no rights* to the system.
- Capture the results

This solution allows you to leverage existing assemblers, loaders and security without having to re-implement them.

---

The best example code of dynamically loading, running and sandboxing C# code I know of is the terrarium game at http://terrarium2.codeplex.com/

However, you might consider something better suited to this job, like a scripting system.  Lua comes to mind as a popular one.  Using Lua users will only be able to perform the actions you allow. http://www.lua.org/

Comment: You want to include machine code that is sandboxed to only output in your program?

Comment: Yes, thats right, and also to only where I specify, so it can't write over any variable it likes no matter what chunk of machine code is run. Also it's machine code I can store and edit.

Comment: I don't know how to go about those things, but it seems like it could be a complicated solution, tyvm for the input. I will try the other solutions first.

Comment: Well the other option is dynamic .NET IL a la terrarium.  Inline asm does not help you if you need it to be editable at run time.

Comment: According to the wiki there is an asm runner in C++ thats a function and takes a std::String, the asm goes in the String.

Comment: And how do you expect to "sandbox" that code unless you write an assembler to check it?

Comment: I think Alex is saying that cirtain instructions can write to arbitary locations in memory, the disk or whatever but others just compute. So it's just a case or constructing the asm to only use safe instructions or in the case of writing to memory only in places that I want. I don't know what each program will do as my program generates and tests thousands of them but I can restrict how they are constructed to ensure they are safe. At least I think I should be able to from what I've found out here.

Comment: Ah, that was unclear from your description -- I assumed you wanted to protect the system from external code -- if you are making the code yourself it should work great.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to include assembler in your C/C++ code, consider either inline assembly routines, or compiling seperate full on assembler files and linking them back in.  Inline assembler syntax is kinda weird, but I believe it is probably the best choice for you from what I've read.

Wikipedia to the rescue for some samples:

[Inline assembler examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_assembler)

Comment: Looks good it's not safe but it does meet some of the other requirements: asm("movl %ecx, %eax");